# AcquireTokenForClient does not return a refresh token?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory

We are not receiving the refresh_token when requesting the token despite the documentation says that always you request a token you will receive a refresh token.
Might be accidentally missing/misunderstanding something ?

This is a piece of the code we are using:

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("...")
  .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "...")
  .WithClientSecret(CLIENTSECRET)
  .Build();

  AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

And here is the reference to the documentation that we are basing our expectation on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#refresh-tokens

> **Refresh tokens**
>
> When a client acquires an access token to access a protected resource, the client also receives a refresh token.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Client Credentials flow here in your code here to acquire the token.

See here for documentation - [IConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.iconfidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenforclient?view=azure-dotnet)

```
  AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Read here about the [Client Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#successful-response-1) in more detail, and specifically what a successful response looks like in this case, which is only expected to have an access_token and no refresh_token.

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBP..."
}
```

A different flow, like Authorization Code flow (usually used by web apps) returns back an access_token as well as a refresh_token.

You can read more about that flow and a response in that case here - [Authorization Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response-1)

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4...",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyZDRkMTFhMi1mODE0LTQ2YTctOD...",
}
```